# C++ OpenCV SURF vs SurfFeatureDetector vs SurfDescriptorExtractor

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

So far I used `cv::SurfFeatureDetector` to get SURF points from an image. Now I want to get the descriptors as well. So, I thought `cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor` is what I need. But, I saw that both `cv::SurfFeatureDetector` and `SurfDescriptorExtractor` can detect SURF points and compute the descriptors. And there is also `cv::SURF` which can do the same things. Is there any difference between these 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/6cd8e9f556c8c55c05178dec05d5277ae00020d9/modules/xfeatures2d/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp#L148) that they are the same:

```
typedef SURF SurfFeatureDetector;
typedef SURF SurfDescriptorExtractor;
```

In practice, `XXXFeatureDetector` and `XXXDescriptorExtractor` are simply common interfaces for the 2 separate tasks, so you can separate the keypoints detection from the descriptor computation, and you can for example detect keypoints with MSER and compute descriptors with SIFT.

---

You can see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/6cd8e9f556c8c55c05178dec05d5277ae00020d9/modules/xfeatures2d/include/opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp#L116) that `SURF inherits from`Feature2D`:

```
class CV_EXPORTS_W SURF : public Feature2D
```

And that `FeatureDetector` and `DescriptorExtractor` are [the same](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/include/opencv2/features2d.hpp#L206) as `Feature2D`:

```
typedef Feature2D FeatureDetector;
typedef Feature2D DescriptorExtractor;
```

The distinction between *FeatureDetector* and *DescriptorExtractor* is:

> Feature detectors in OpenCV have wrappers with a common interface that enables you to easily switch between different algorithms solving the same problem. All objects that implement keypoint detectors inherit the FeatureDetector interface.

The *common problem* is to extract the `KeyPoint`s.

> Extractors of keypoint descriptors in OpenCV have wrappers with a common interface that enables you to easily switch between different algorithms solving the same problem. This section is devoted to **computing descriptors represented as vectors in a multidimensional space**. All objects that implement the vector descriptor extractors inherit the DescriptorExtractor interface.

This distinction is useful to separate the task of finding the *keypoints* from the task of computing the descriptor, since not all methods can do both. E.g. MSER is just a feature detector, but doesn't compute the descriptors.